# Using UIAlertViews inside a for loop to sum numbers in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

I'm trying to use UIAlertViews inside a for loop to sum numbers which shall be input in the alert view's text box but the problem is that the alert shows up as many times as the for loop runs and I don't know how to make the loop wait for a button press on the alert view and then loop again. In the example below, I want the alert view to appear three times so that I can enter three numbers and then find the sum of those numbers. Can someone please help me in this? Below is my code. Thanks

```
int noOfInductorsSelected=3;

for (int i=1; i<=noOfInductorsSelected; i++) {
    NSString *counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Value for Inductor no %d :",i];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inductance Value" message:counter delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to come up with a working example, but basically you have to implement the alert view delegate method that is called when they hit okay, check to see how many times it has been called, and call it again from there if needed.

Comment: Yes, I made an alert view function and called it in the alert view delegate method where I did my calculations and simultaneously checked how many times it needed to be called with the help of a counter variable. Thanks a lot.. !

Answer (score 2):

That's a fairly questionable interface, you may want to consider thinking about what you need and if there is a better way to collect that information.

However, if you must do it that way, instead of running your alert in a for loop, you'd need an instance variable to store the number of iterations and the sum of the values entered so far.  Then, in

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

where you're getting the value the user entered, you'd increment your counter and call the method to display the alert again. I'm not sure if you should display an alert directly from alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:, but you'd probably be better off to use performSelecter:wihtObject:afterDelay: so the app can continue properly through the run loop.

Comment: Yea, the for loop was no good so I had to use the didDismissWithButtonIndex delegate method with a counter to show the alerts and do the calculations as well. Thanks a lot for the help.. :)